# Git - how to move last X commits on master to a feature branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

Let's say I'm on master (at C4), and stuff is broken but it was working back at commit C1. How can I effectively copy all commits up to C4 to a new branch to preserve the unstable code, and then roll master back to C1? (this is so I can push it to GitHub and have continuous deployment push master code to the live server)

I know the first step is to branch the feature off of master as is, but then how do I roll back master to commit C1?

Comment: Give C4 a useful branch name. Move master to C1. The 'names' of branches in Git are simply monikors for a particular SHA1/commit and can be changed at will. (By default the branch name is moved forward with a commit; but it is a monikor that is updated to refer to a new commit - this makes Git differ from most other SCMs.)

Comment: To answer your question about rolling back the branch: `git reset --hard C1` (after saving your current with a branch or tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b holdingBranch
```

This will create a new branch based on the current master. Then you can roll back on master with

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard C1
```

without affecting the new branch and successfully rolling back master

Answer (score 1):

```
$git checkout master
$git branch testing
$git checkout master
$git reset --hard hash_of_your_C1(like de79f21269b02125e50cf788fa83e91)
$git push origin master
```

That should works, you can always check your testing development with

```
$git checkout testing
```